# How to re-download .gradle file in android

Tags: java, android

I had faced a issue `diroutput=null` so for that I searched on Google and found that I have to delete `.gradle` file by using command `rm - r .gradle` it solved the issue but now when I create new project I get cannot resolve dependencies and could not load modules and neither my app level gradle is getting generated. I'm having hard time understanding the problem.

Comment: As of my knowledge .gradle folder auto generates if not exist. Can you post what you see in logs?

Comment: @Khemraj It is only generated when you create a new project.

Comment: Actually your question is not clear, here can be 3 things referred by you, app level build.gradle, project level build.gradle, and .gradle folder.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice where you from dude. i am talking about .gradle folder.

Comment: @Khemraj You are right. The question is unclear. I thought the OP is asking about the `build.gradle` file, but they could be asking about the `.gradle` folder instead.

Comment: Okay when you create a new project then you don't get app level build.gradle file?

Comment: When I create a new project app level build.gradle file is not getting generated

Comment: Can you paste what project structure android makes for you? post a screenshot

Comment: And everything is shown in red this has started happening since I deleted .gradle file

Answer (score 0):

`build.gradle` is created when you create a new Android Studio project. You can either recreate the file manually or create a new project and copy your code into it. Either way, there is no way to just download a new `build.gradle`.